# UITableView only shows 1 cell when it should show 2 cells (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

So I have 3 cells: `SenderCell`, `ReceiverCell` , and a default blank `Cell`

I want the mainTableView to show all messages from both sender and receiver, which are contained in `messageFromCurrentUserArray` and `messageFromReceiverArray` respectively. Unfortunately, whenever I run the code below, it only shows either cell. I would like to show both cells if their arrays aren't empty. Hoping someone could help me. Thanks in advance!

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return allMessages.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    if indexPath.row < messageFromCurrentUserArray.count {

        let cell = mainTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SenderCell", for: indexPath) as! SenderTableViewCell

        cell.senderMessage.text = messageFromCurrentUserArray[indexPath.row]

        mainTableView.beginUpdates()
        cell.senderMessage.sizeToFit()
        let imageFile = PFUser.current()?["profilePhoto"] as! PFFile
        imageFile.getDataInBackground(block: { (data, error) in

            if let imageData = data {

                self.currentUserImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!

            }

        })

        cell.senderProfilePhoto.image = currentUserImage
        cell.senderProfilePhoto.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cell.senderProfilePhoto.layer.cornerRadius = cell.senderProfilePhoto.frame.height / 2
        cell.senderProfilePhoto.clipsToBounds = true
        mainTableView.endUpdates()

        return cell

    } else if indexPath.row < messageFromReceiverArray.count {

        let cell = mainTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReceiverCell", for: indexPath) as! ReceiverTableViewCell
        cell.receiverMessage.text = messageFromReceiverArray[indexPath.row]

        mainTableView.beginUpdates()
        cell.receiverMessage.sizeToFit()
        cell.receiverProfilePhoto.image = receiverImage
        cell.receiverProfilePhoto.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cell.receiverProfilePhoto.layer.cornerRadius = cell.receiverProfilePhoto.frame.height / 2
        cell.receiverProfilePhoto.clipsToBounds = true
        mainTableView.endUpdates()

        return cell

    } else {

        let cell = mainTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CellTableViewCell
        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the comparsion in the outer if statements:

```
if indexPath.row < messageFromCurrentUserArray.count {
    //...
} else if indexPath.row < messageFromReceiverArray.count {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Since all the `count`s in the arrays start with index `0` and stop at their count each, but your indexPath.row will go up to the the sum of both (e.g. `messageFromCurrentUserArray.count + messageFromReceiverArray.count`)

You'll have to change the second `if` clause and the index access to something like

```
} else if indexPath.row < (messageFromCurrentUserArray.count + messageFromReceiverArray.count) {
    // ...
    int receiverIndex = indexPath.row - messageFromCurrentUserArray.count
    cell.receiverMessage.text = messageFromReceiverArray[receiverIndex]
    // or: cell.receiverMessage.text = allMessages[indexPath.row]
    // ...
}   else {
    // ...
}
```